# Problem with AxesLabel and LegendLabel

Tags: plotting, labeling

I'm trying to combine VectorPlot and DensityPlot on the same graph. So I have:

```
p1=VectorPlot[function1, {x,a,b}, {y,a,b}, PlotLabel -> "vectors function1"  , VectorPoints -> Fine, VectorStyle -> Black, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

and

```
p2 = DensityPlot[function2, {x, a, b}, {y, a, b}, PlotLabel -> "density function2"  , PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

and in order to combine them I used

```
plot1 = Show[{p2, p1}, PlotLabel -> "function1 and function2"]
```

a and b are constants I set at the beginning of the code.
Now, the problem is that in all of the graphs the axes labels is not shown. even when I'm trying to add it to the Show function it shows the graph without the axes labels. I have another regular Plot in my code and there the axes label works fine.

Also, it seems that LegendLabel is not working. When I'm adding it to densityplot the code doesn't recognize that function. Also when I'm trying to add it to Show, error appears:

```
OptionValue: Unknown option LegendLabel for Graphics.
```

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: By default, `VectorPlot` (and `DensityPlot`) use `Frame` and `FrameLabel` instead of `Axes` and `AxesLabel`. That's why the axis labels aren't showing up.  As for `LegendLabel`, it's an option to `BarLegend`, so you want to use `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "label"]`.

Comment: Also, the function `VectorDensityPlot` will allow you to do this all at once if you're interested.